# Built-in Wardrobe Using Silicone / Sealant to attach to Wall

Tags: silicone, wardrobe

I've just removed an in-built wardrobe in our new-build apartment and have realised that they only used sealant to secure it to the walls and ceiling.

This was an L-shaped wardrobe in an L-shaped nook. The wardrobe was a hybrid between a front frame and carcass, i.e. it had its own walls, floating shelves, floor, but no ceiling, no back and nothing was screwed into the room's actual walls.

The shelves and floor of the wardrobe held the walls of the wardobe together, giving it some structure. My question is if I were to install a new in-built wardrobe (using the remenants of my old wardrobe), would attaching it to the room's walls and ceiling solely using silicone or sealant be adaquate? I would have a shelf and a floor to give the walls rigidity but no ceiling and no back.

Comment: Was the wardrobe pretty stable before you hacked it out? If so, that's probably a reasonable way of installing the new one. BTW - what was the "sealant" that was used? Was it something like a silicone caulk, or was it a construction adhesive? A construction adhesive (like LiquidNails™, for example) should be _more_ than sufficient. Caulk (silicone or acrylic) is probably not.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion (risk tolerance) and the nuances of the situation. Silicone can hold very well, but only if enough is used and the surfaces being bonded are stable. No one can really know for sure from what you've told us and _you_ have to decide what you'll accept.

Comment: It was definitely silicone or a hybrid - super stretchy but I could not move any of the peices of wood without cutting a significant portion of the silicone off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a real safety concern with bookshelves, wardrobes, etc. They can tip over onto children (adults too, but children are more vulnerable because they are smaller and more likely to climb on things) who climb on them, pull hard on them, etc. That is the biggest reason, in my mind, for attaching furniture to walls, usually with brackets and screws.

However, an *L-shaped* wardrobe is likely **much** harder to tip over than a typical rectangular piece of furniture. If tipover risk is extremely low (may be nearly impossible, depending on design) then using some sort of sealant to attach to the wall instead of brackets and screws is reasonable.

That being said, if you can locate studs or other appropriate places to attach brackets then brackets and screws might actually be easier than sealant, and is guaranteed to be very secure.

Comment: isn't the sealant purely cosmetic?  I don't think it has any anchoring value.

Comment: I think sealant would have *some* anchoring value. Enough to stop some annoying minor movements when putting things on shelves, etc. But not *nearly* enough to provide safety from tipover.

Comment: Dabs of silicone are often used as mounting mechanisms. I've done it and seen it done a zillion times. No one would caulk furniture for appearance.